# Post-thumbnail only for specific post-types?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, post-thumbnails, add-theme-support

I have this in my `functions.php`

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

This means all my post-types (normal posts and custom-post-types) have post-thumbnails enabled.

Is it possible to just enable them inside a custom-post-type and not on normal posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`remove_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support) to disable features for specific post types.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa63635_init' );
function wpa63635_init() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'thumbnail' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a "supports" argument when registering the Custom Post type, you can leave out "thumbnail" which will disable it for that post-type.

See the Codex entry for [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) and look at the 'supports' argument.